Transversality for Morse homology on manifold with boundary
I'm trying to make my own argument for a situation where $X$ is a smooth manifold with boundary and $f$ a Morse function. The vector field $V=-grad f$ and we denote $D_p, A_q$ as the unstable manifold of $p$ and stable manifold of $q$ respectively, $p,q\in \partial X$. (I'm imagining $X$ to be the right hemisphere, $p$ is the North Pole and $q$ is the South Pole).
$A_q= \{ x\in X \mid \lim_{s\to \infty} \psi_s(x)=q\}, D_p= \{ x\in X \mid \lim_{s\to -\infty} \psi_s(x)=p\}$, where $\psi$ is a 1-parameter family of diffeomorphisms on $X$.
Assumptions:

$(D_p \cap \partial X) \pitchfork (A_q \cap \partial X)$ in $\partial X$
$ind_{\partial X}(q)=ind_{X}(q)$, meaning the index of critical point $q$ is the same when viewed in $\partial X$ and $X$.

Claim: Assuming that for any $z$ in a neighborhood of $q$,
$$ T_zA_q + T_z\partial X = T_zX,$$ then $D_p \pitchfork A_q$ in $X$, i.e., $T_zD_p+T_zA_q=T_zX$.
I'm almost certain that this claim is true, but I can't figure out how to finish my argument. If others have an alternative approach, please feel free to share! I'm be happy to learn.
This is my argument so far:
We know that we can decompose $T_qX=E_{-}(q)\oplus E_{+}(q)$, where $E_-(q)$ and $E_+(q)$ are respectively the negative and positive eigenspace of $Hess_f(q)$.
We can further write $E_{+}(q)=(E_{+}(q)\cap \partial X) \oplus (E_{+}(q) \cap \partial X)^{\perp}$, where the $\perp$ represents the perpendicular space. So then we have that $$T_qX=E_{-}(q)\oplus (E_{+}(q)\cap \partial X) \oplus (E_{+}(q) \cap \partial X)^{\perp}.$$
Then we use the fact that $ind_{\partial X}(q)=ind_{X}(q)$ to say that $E_{-}(q)=E_{-}(q)\cap \partial X$, therefore by our assumption (1), we have
$$T_q\partial X = T_q(A_q\cap \partial X) +T_q(D_p\cap \partial X)=E_{-}(q)\oplus (E_{+} \cap \partial X).$$
Then we can rewrite  $$T_qX=T_q(A_q\cap \partial X) +T_q(D_p\cap \partial X) \oplus (E_{+}(q) \cap \partial X)^{\perp}=T_q(A_q\cap \partial X) +T_q(D_p\cap \partial X),$$ where if I'm note mistaken, $T_q(D_q\cap \partial X)=(E_{+}(q) \cap \partial X)^{\perp}$.
Then I just don't know how to get rid of the extra $\partial X$ I have in the last equality. But I'm sure there are other issues in my proof. I'm also heuristically using things like $E_{-}(q)\cong T_qD_q$ in the background.
